# Delegate issue when customizing UISearchController and UISearchBar in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, searchbar

In my tableViewController, I need to have search function as one of features, and it conforms to these delegates, one of which is the subclass of UISearchController's delegate.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, CustomSearchControllerDelegate {

    var customSearchController: CustomSearchController!

    func addCustomSearchBar() {
        customSearchController = CustomSearchController(...)

        /* detail setting and add the customSearchBar */

        customSearchController.customDelegate = self
        customSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        /* implement customDelegate method */

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let searchString = customSearchController.customSearchBar.text else {
        return
        }

        newArray = dataArray.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let text:NSString = text

        return (text.rangeOfString(searchString!, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch).location) != NSNotFound
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
           /*-----------won't work-------------*/
        }

    }
```

And my subclass of UISearchController as below,

```
class CustomSearchController: UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate{
    var customSearchBar: CustomSearchBar! //subclass of UISearchBar
    var customDelegate: CustomSearchControllerDelegate!

        ...

    init(...) {
    self.mySearchBar(...)
    }

   func mySearchBar(...) {
       customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar(...)

       /* detail setting */

       customSearchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        customDelegate.didStartSearching()
}


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        customSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        customDelegate.didTapOnSearchButton()
} 


    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        customSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        customDelegate.didTapOnCancelButton()
}
```

As you can see, this subclass has its own delegate for handling the `UISearchBarDelegate`.

And the question is that, **why the UISearchResultsUpdating delegate method won't work?**, I think the UISearchResultsUpdating delegate would work as well.

I know I can implement UISearchBarDelegate method in my subclass of UISearchController `func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange: searchText: String)` as substitute method for searching when typing text in search bar.

But I am really wondering why it won't work here, thank you for helping me.

If any ambiguity, please comment below, thanks again!

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue with a simpler example. Using the built in search bar and I still can't access `tableView` in the UISearchResultsUpdating delegate method :/